# Template to render is unable to find

Tags: php, symfony

I know there are similar questions like that, but the errors don't apply to me.

So I'm trying to render a template in my `LuckyController.php` file which looks like that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class LuckyController extends AbstractController{

    /**
     * 
     *@Route("/lucky/number") 
     */

    public function number(){


        $number = random_int(0,100);

        return $this->render('lucky/number.html.twig',[
            'number' => $number, 
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then, I have the `base.html.twig` template that I want to render:

```
{# templates/lucky/number.html.twig #}
   <h1> Your lucky number is {{ number }} </h1>
```

This is a part of my file structure that could be eventually relevant:

```
Project
|
--src
   |
   --Controller
         |
         -- LuckyController.php
--templates
   |
   -- number.html.twig
```

The problem that I have:

> Unable to find template "templates/number.html.twig" (looked into: ~\symfony\Project/templates, 
>       ~\symfony\Project\vendor\symfony\twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form).

Comment: Where is `number.html.twig` located? From the error, it's looking to get it from the `templates` folder... Can you update your file structure by integrating it?

Comment: number.html.twig is located in my templates.

Comment: Are you calling that page from anywhere else? Because it is looking to get that file in `~\symfony\Project/templates/templates/`, like if you did `->render('templates/number.html.twig', ...)`.

Comment: I'm just calling it from the number function in LuckyController.php. I've been following this tutorial: https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html step by step.

Comment: But even as it is now, in your `Controller`, you're asking for `lucky/number.html.twig` while you don't even have the `lucky` folder in your `templates` folder.

Comment: I changed the path to templates/number.html.twig. But it still doesn't find it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185630/discussion-between-marc-andre-and-testoo).

Comment: Just: return $this->render('number.html.twig' ...

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/templating.html#referencing-templates-in-a-bundle, (@BundleName/directory/filename.html.twig)

Comment: can you add an up vote in the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should put your twig file in a subfolder of "templates" and call it "lucky" so the path to your twig template should be: templates/lucky/number.html.twig and not directly under templates

```
--templates
   |
   -- lucky
       |
       -- number.html.twig
```